# AngularJs filter search after user press 'entrer'

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am going to implement a searchbox wherein user will input the string on the searchbox and will be filtered when button is clicked/submitted/pressed enter.

I am retrieving so much data from my database and it makes my app loads very slow. So I need to make the search not retrieve all the data (causes logged of computer).

Ok .. So here's my view

```
 <div data-ng-app="PRApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="PRCtrl" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="row">
                <form data-ng-submit="changeDate()">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h4><b>Search by Date :</b></h4>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span data-ng-click="show=!show" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input data-show="{{show}}" type="text" name="filter_fromDate" datepicker data-ng-model="filter_fromDate"
                                    class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" data-ng-minlength="10" />

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span data-ng-click="show=!show" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input data-show="{{show}}" type="text" name="filter_toDate" datepicker data-ng-model="filter_toDate"
                                    class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" data-ng-minlength="10" />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="GO" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>

                <div class="col-xs-4">

                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <h4><b>Search :</b></h4>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" name="search" data-ng-model="filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here (e.g. 151234 or Pille)" />
                        </div>
                        <br />

                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button data-ng-click="exportData()" class ="btn btn-warning"><i class ="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i>Export to Excel </button>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 data-ng-show="models == null ">Loading ...</h2>
        <br />

        <div id="exportable">
            <table data-ng-show="models != null" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                id="PRTable">

                <tr class="titlerow">
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='RequestDate'; reverse = !reverse">PR Date <span
                            data-ng-show="sorting == 'RequestDate'"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='RequestID '; reverse = !reverse">PR # <span data-ng-show="sorting == 'RequestID '">
                        </span>
                        </a>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='PARNumber '; reverse = !reverse">PAR # <span
                            data-ng-show="sorting == 'PARNumber '"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='ProgramName '; reverse = !reverse">Program <span
                            data-ng-show="sorting == 'ProgramName '"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='FullName '; reverse = !reverse">Requestor <span
                            data-ng-show="sorting == 'FullName '"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='PONo'; reverse = !reverse">PO # 
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='StatusID '; reverse = !reverse">PRStatus<span
                            data-ng-show="sorting == 'StatusID '"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='Amount '; reverse = !reverse">Total Amount<span
                            data-ng-show="sorting == 'Amount '"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>

                                            <th>
                        <a href="#" data-ng-click="sorting='Amount '; reverse = !reverse">Last Action<span
                            data-ng-show="sorting == 'Amount '"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>


                <tr data-ng-repeat="model in models  | orderBy: sorting:reverse | filter : filter ">

                    <td>{{jsonDatetotext(model.RequestDate) | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModalContent" data-ng-click="getSelectedPR(model)">
                            {{model.RequestID}}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{model.PARNumber }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.ProgramName }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.FullName }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.PONo}}</td>
                    <td>{{StatusList[model.StatusID] | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td class="totalAmount"><span class="pull-right">{{model.TotalAmount | number:2}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{model.LastBy | lowercase}}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9" ><h3><b>Total Amount : </b><span class="pull-right">{{models | sumbykey : 'TotalAmount' | number:2}}</span></h3> </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.Modal Na ni -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="basicModalContent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="exportablePRItems">
                        <div class="table-responsive">

                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th>PR #
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Item Description
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Supplier 
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Account
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Currency
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Amount
                                        </th>

                                        <th>(USD) Amount
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody data-ng-repeat="selectedPR in selectedModal.ItemList">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.RequestID}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.PartDesc}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.SupplierID }}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.AccountType}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.CurrName }}</td>
                                        <td data-ng-model="amount" class="amount">{{selectedPR.Amount | number:2}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.AmountUSD}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></span></td>
                                    <td colspan="6"><b>Total Amount : </b>{{selectedModal.ItemList | sumbykey : 'Amount' | number:2}} </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <footer>
                            <br />
                                   <button data-ng-click="exportDataItems()" class ="btn btn-warning"><i class ="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i>Export Item </button></footer>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <button id="btnModalCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->

                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

And here is my angular:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var PRApp = angular.module('PRApp', []);
    PRApp.controller('PRCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http) {

        http.get('GetList').success(function (data) {

            scope.models = data;
            scope.selectedModal = null;
        });
        scope.getStatus = http.get('GetStatusList').success(function (status) {
            scope.StatusList = status
        });

        scope.getSelectedPR = function (PR) {
            scope.selectedModal = PR;
        };


        //scope.totalPrice = function () {
        //    var total = 0; 
        //    var amounts = this.closest('td').find('.totalAmount').text();
        //    angular.forEach($scope.models.data, function (item) {
        //        total += $(amounts).parseInt;
        //    })


        //    return total;
        //}
        //   scope.searchHere = 'Search here ... '



        scope.isEmpty = function (items) {
            return angular.isArray(items) && items.length === 0;
        };


        function GetbyDate(fr, t) {
            var from = new Date(t)
        };

        scope.changeDate = function () {
            scope.models = null;
            http.get('GetReportList?from=' + scope.filter_fromDate + '&to=' + scope.filter_toDate).success(
                function (data) {
                    scope.models = data;
                });
        }
        scope.jsonDatetotext = function (jsondate) {
            // jsondate format: /Date(#############)/
            // substr(6) will remove '/Date('
            // parseInt will convert remaing string '#############' to int and ignores ')/'
            return new Date(parseInt(jsondate.substr(6)));
        };


        scope.exportData = function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate();
            var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"

            });
            saveAs(blob, "Report_" + d + ".xls");
        };

        scope.exportDataItems = function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate();
            var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportablePRItems').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"

            });
            saveAs(blob, "Items_"+ d +".xls");
        };


    }]);


    PRApp.directive('datepicker', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {

                attr.$observe("show", function (val) {
                    if (val == 'true') {
                        $(el).datepicker("show");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(el).datepicker("hide");
                    }
                });


                $(el).datepicker({
                    minDate: '-5Y',
                    maxDate: 0,
                    dateFormat: 'MM d, yy',
                    onSelect: function (dateText) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });




    PRApp.filter('sumbykey', function () {
        return function (data, key) {
            if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
                return 0;
            }

            var sum = 0.00;
            for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                sum += parseFloat(data[i][key]);
            }

            return sum;
        };

    });



</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the html of your ng-repeat and the code in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use server side paging. See the example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-43e5de16)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I almost had finished my works. I already have my pages. I just need to make a button function on angular that would filter the data after 'enter' is pressed or after button is clicked. Because when I use the normal filter (data binding) it is not really very good. It's slow.. especially when my record are more than a thousands.